# jQuery :contains skipping match including &amp;

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here's the code

```
$(function() {
        $(".category-list li ul li").children("a").each(function (){
          var subListName = $(this).html();
          var subListContent = $(this).next("ul").clone();
          $(".subcat-grid ul li a:contains("+ subListName +")").after(subListContent);
        });
    });
```

Everything is matching up properly but the one `subListName` that uses `&amp;` is returning `false` in `$(".subcat-grid ul li a:contains("+ subListName +")")` and so the content is not being added.

I checked the values of the variables `subListName` and the return value of `$(".subcat-grid ul li a")` and it looks like they should be matching. I don't know why `:contains` is skipping values with `&amp;`

Comment: the `&` is probably `&amp;`, i wonder if that has anything to do with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `.text` to get the text, otherwise characters such as `&` will be converted to `&amp;` which won't work because `:contains` matches on the `innerText`, not the `innerHTML`

```
$(function() {
    $(".category-list li ul li").children("a").each(function (){
      var subListName = $(this).text();
      var subListContent = $(this).next("ul").clone();
      $(".subcat-grid ul li a:contains("+ subListName +")").after(subListContent);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you handle strings, always look at the result.

In this case, your selector would be:

```
.subcat-grid ul li a:contains(x & y)
```

This is incorrect. Try:

```
.subcat-grid ul li a:contains('x & y')
```

ie. wrap your contents with quotes.